# "Export to excel" button kendogrid download more than 1 file

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have a function that creates a kendo grid which has the button to download it as a ".xlsx" file.
There is a dropdown that when is changed, calls this function again.

```
function CreateGrid(result) {

    var chartSeries = result.ChartData;
    var gName = $("#dropdown1 option:selected").text();
    // Create Grid
    $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
            fileName: "Grid1_"+gName+".xlsx",
            filterable: true,
            allPages: true
        },
        columns: [
            { field: "column1", width: "90px", title: "<strong>Item1</strong>" },
            { field: "column2", width: "80px", title: "<strong>Item2</strong>" },
            { field: "column3", width: "120px", title: "<strong>Item3</strong>", format: "{0:c2}" }

        ],
        groupable: false,
        resizable: true,
        pageable: false,
        scrollable: true,
        filterable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageSize: 50
    });

    // Set Grid data source
    $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(
        new kendo.data.DataSource({
            //Set the data of the grid as the result array of object.
            data: result.ChartData
        })
    );
}
```

The problem is, when i click in the button to download the file, it downloads every grid previously made when I want only the current one.
For example, i created the grid once, then i changed the dropdown and the grid changed to the values corresponding to the new dropdown value, but when I click in the button, it downloads 2 files, from the first grid made and the one showing.
If I change the dropdown again, then the values will change according to the dropdown value but if I click to download the file,it downloads the previous 2 files + the one in the grid.

It seems that even thought i cant see the previous grids anymore, they are still there so I want to know how can I destroy/erase/clean them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to remove the grid before creating a new one. This function would delete it and also would return you the current data in the grid, if you want to re-assign it:

```
function removeGrid(g) {
    var tmp = [];
    try {
        tmp = g.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    } catch (e) { }
    var container = g.parent();
    g.remove();
    container.append("<div id='" + g.attr("id") + "' class='" + g.attr("class") + "'></div>");
    return tmp;
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
var gName = $("#dropdown1 option:selected").text();
removeGrid($("#grid1"));
// Create Grid
$("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    ...
}
```